# Tcl parameter list clarification

Tags: tcl

I came across the following and cannot figure out what this parameter list means:

```
proc IsSpecificationLive { specificationDate { onDate "" } }
```

More specifically, what is the purpose of `{ onDate"" }` being inside the parameter list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empty default value for the optional argument `onDate`.

From the manual page of [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/proc.htm)

> *Args* specifies the formal arguments to the procedure. It consists of a list, possibly empty, each of whose elements specifies one argument. Each argument specifier is also a list with either one or two fields. If there is only a single field in the specifier then it is the name of the argument; if there are two fields, then the first is the argument name and the second is its default value. Arguments with default values that are followed by non-defaulted arguments become required arguments. In 8.6 this will be considered an error.

Example:

```
proc IsSpecificationLive { specificationDate { onDate "" } } {
    puts $onDate
}

IsSpecificationLive foo bar; # outputs "bar"
IsSpecificationLive baz; # outputs an empty line
```

See the documentation for [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/proc.htm) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

That is the syntax for optional parameters.  So, this procedure takes two parameters.  The first is required (specificationDate),  the second is optional.  If the procedure is called with only one parameter, onDate will be set to "".  If it is called with two parameters, onDate will be set to whatever the second parameter is.

Answer (score 1):

That allows you to invoke the procedure with a single argument, and the default value for `onDate` will be the empty string. Here's a snippet from an interactive tclsh session:

```
% proc IsSpecificationLive { specificationDate { onDate "" } } {
    puts $specificationDate
    puts $onDate
}
% IsSpecificationLive
wrong # args: should be "IsSpecificationLive specificationDate ?onDate?"
% IsSpecificationLive one two
one
two
% IsSpecificationLive one 
one

% IsSpecificationLive one two three
wrong # args: should be "IsSpecificationLive specificationDate ?onDate?"
```